# How to add properties to styled component with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have components like this

```
import React from 'react';

import styled from '../../styled-components';

const StyledInput = styled.input`
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: 50%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline: none;
    background: ${(props) => props.theme.color.background};
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
`
;

export const Input = () => {
    return <StyledInput placeholder="All notes"></StyledInput>
}
```

I want to place them as property on "index" component like this

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

import { Input } from './Input';

const NoteTags:any = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 20%;
    height: 5%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid ${(props) => props.theme.color.background}; `;

NoteTags.Input = Input;

export default NoteTags;
```

So then I can use them like this

```
import React from 'react';

import NoteTags from '../../blocks/note-tags';

const ComponentNoteTags = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <NoteTags.Input></NoteTags.Input>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default ComponentNoteTags;
```

The problem with this is that property `Input` doesn't exist on `NoteTags`  so typescript gives me an error. I can solve it by setting type `any` to `NoteTags` but I'm not sure that it is the best way.

Is there a better way to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**

I found it much better to use a type helper to add extra properties into a component's variable:

```
// type-helper.ts
export function withProperties<A, B>(component: A, properties: B): A & B {
  Object.keys(properties).forEach(key => {
    component[key] = properties[key]
  });
  return component as A & B;
}
```

> Note: @Allan points out in the comment, type assertion might be necessary like so:
>
> ```
> (component as any)[key] = (properties as any)[key]
> ```
>
> to avoid typescript complaining about `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature`.

We're just passing each property in `properties` to `component` and give it a joined type of both. Then we can 'glue' sub components into a main component as follow:

```
// component/index.ts
import MainComponent from './MainComponent';
import SubComponent1 from './SubComponent1';
import SubComponent2 from './SubComponent2';
import { withProperties } from '../type-helper.ts';

export withProperties(MainComponent, { SubComponent1, SubComponent2 })
```

and use it as usual

```
import MainComponent from './Component';

export default () => (
  <MainComponent>
    <SubComponent1 />
    <SubComponent2 />
  </MainComponent>
)
```

This approach works with normal React component as well & not just styled components one, so I think it's better.

Here's a [codesandbox demo with both approaches I've shared](https://codesandbox.io/s/n3q2k82rll?fontsize=14), one of each use your code.

---

**Previous answer**

Assuming you're using the latest packages:

```
"styled-components": "^4.1.3",
"@types/styled-components": "^4.1.10",
```

You can create an [interection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) that include both the type of the parent & child components:

```
import styled, { StyledComponent } from 'styled-components'
import ChildComponent from '...'

type Component = StyledComponent<'div', any> & {
    ChildComponent: /* your component type */
}

interface IProps {
  ...
}

// create styled component per usual
const MyComponent = styled.div<IProps>`
  ...
` as Component

MyComponent.ChildComponent = ChildComponent;
```

Here's the [`StyledComponent` definition](http://export%20type%20StyledComponent%3C):

```
export type StyledComponent<
    C extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | React.ComponentType<any>,
    T extends object,       // theme interface
    O extends object = {},  // props interface
    A extends keyof any = never
> = string & StyledComponentBase<C, T, O, A>;
```

You can use it as `StyledComponent<C, T, O, A>` or `StyledComponent<C, T>`

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get it working by defining the call signatures of the styled component and the additional properties you want to add. Typescript will complain that `Item` doesn't exist on `List`, so I had to use Object Assign to create the styled component and assign the property simultaneously.

```ts
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { PropsWithChildren, ReactElement } from 'react'

interface ListOverload {
    ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<{}>): ReactElement
    Item({ children }: PropsWithChildren<{}>): ReactElement
}

export const Item = styled.li(
    ({ theme }) => css`
        padding: ${theme.space.md};
        border-bottom: 1px solid ${theme.colors.greyLight};
    `
)

export const List: ListOverload = Object.assign(
    styled.ul`
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    `,
    { Item }
)
```

Then you can use like this in your JSX:

```
<List>
  <List.Item>Todo 1</List.Item>
  <List.Item>Todo 2</List.Item>
  <List.Item>Todo 3</List.Item>
</List>
```